# Django как добавить новые поля к базовой форме региcтрации

Tags: django, python-3.7

Тут мне надо добавить много новых полей для регистрации пользователя, но выводит ошибку. Вот сам код:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from home.models import Locations, Levels

class User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/img/profile/', blank=True)
    levels = models.ManyToManyField(Levels, verbose_name='levls')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, db_index=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, db_index=True)
    birdate = models.DateField()
    telnum = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    levelreg = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    levelchange = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120)
    aside = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    bside = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    friendusers = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    rebuy = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
    balls = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user.username)
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
from django import forms

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',  widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'name', 'first_name', 'birdate', 'telnum', 'email', 'aside', 'bside','rebuy', 'balls', 'total')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
           raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('photo',)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, UserForm
from .models import User

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
         profile_form = UserForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

         if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
             new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
             new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])

             new_user.save()
             new_user.refresh_from_db()

             new_profile = User.objects.create(user=new_user, 
             photo=request.FILES['photo'])
             new_profile.save()

             return render(request, 'users/login.html', {
                 'new_user': new_user,
                 'new_profile': new_profile
             })
     else:
         user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
         new_profile = UserForm()
       return render(request, 'users/registr.html', {
       'user_form': user_form,
       'new_profile': new_profile
       })
```

заранее благодарен

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45708288/11214129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вам стоит добавить поля `password`, `password2` и другие поля из базовой модели в `fields` и в форму. При сохранении формы, сначала создаете объект базового юзера, потом его профиль.

А еще лучше - можно разделить на 2 формы и обрабатывать обе. Сначала работаете с формой юзера, сохраняете, а затем передаете во вторую форму созданного юзера через initial и тоже сохраняете.

Вот пример:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User # Базовая модель, основная
        fields = '__all__'
    ....

clas ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile # Ваша модель профиля
        fields = '__all__'

    # Поле юзера надо скрыть, это можно сделать через смену виджета на HiddenInput,  если оно обязательно. Можно через Meta, не помню параметр, либо через __init__

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwags):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].widget = HiddenInput()


# Далее код из view'хи

if form_user.is_valid():
    user = form_user.save()
    form_profile = FormProfile(request.POST, request.FILES, initial=dict(user=user))
    if form_profile.is_valid():
        form_profile.save()
```

А чтобы не было ошибок, что пользователь создался без профиля, то оберните блок сохранения в транзакцию

```
with transaction.atomic();
   ... # блок вализации и сохранения форм
```